# Define parameter in pyomo from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, optimization, pyomo

First time pyomo user here.

I have a function that defines a model

```
def define_problem(SET_gen, SET_time, SET_buses, demand):                       

    model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

    #Define sets
    model.SET_GEN   = pyo.Set(initialize = SET_gen) #Set of generators
    model.SET_TIME = pyo.Set(initialize = SET_time) #Set of hours
    model.SET_BUSES = pyo.Set(initialize = SET_buses)   #Set of buses

    #Define parameters
    model.DEMAND = pyo.Param(model.SET_BUSES, model.SET_TIME, initialize = demand_init)
...
```

The argument 'demand' in the function is a pandas DataFrame

The function demand_init is define as the following

```
def demand_init(model, bus, t, data = demand):
    if(bus in set(data.columns)):
        return data.loc[t,bus]
    return 0.0
```

It should define the parameter model.DEMAND for each hour and each bus as the corresponding 'cell' in the demand DataFrame, and 0 if the bus is not in the DataFrame. **EDIT:** Is defined outside the define_problem function.

But its not working. How can i define the parameters of my function from a pandas DataFrame?

> EDIT: Thanks for the answers!

The demand data frame looks like this:

```
      Bus1  Bus10  Bus11  Bus12  ...     Bus6  Bus7  Bus8   Bus9
Hour                             ...                            
1      0.0   9.00   3.50   6.10  ...    11.20   0.0   0.0  29.50
2      0.0   7.34   2.85   4.97  ...     9.13   0.0   0.0  24.06
3      0.0   6.45   2.51   4.37  ...     8.03   0.0   0.0  21.14
4      0.0   5.78   2.25   3.92  ...     7.20   0.0   0.0  18.95
5      0.0   5.56   2.16   3.77  ...     6.92   0.0   0.0  18.22

[5 rows x 14 columns]
```

The 't' and the 'bus' that should get into the demand_init function are the numbers in the index and the names of the columns in the data frame. They are in the sets model.SET_HOURS and model.SET_BUSES respectively.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide an example of what a few rows of your dataframe contain? It might also be helpful to know what values for `bus` and `t` are being passed to your `demand_init` function. Finally, you might find it helpful to look over this post that describes [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, where is your demand_init defined? `rule` will not pass additional arguments to the function. It would make more sense to define your demand_init within define_problem

Comment: Hi! Just made some edit answering your questions. I'll try defining the demand_init function inside the define_problem function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have this one covered, so I'm just providing a couple of suggestions:

It's going to make your life much easier to just call the columns 1,2 etc. and call the *axis* `bus`, instead of calling each columns `"Bus1"` etc.

```py
from pyomo import environ as pye
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
​
n_bus = 5
n_hours = 10
​
demand_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = np.random.random(size=(n_hours, n_bus)),
    columns = np.arange(1, n_bus+1), 
    index = np.arange(1, n_hours+1))
​
demand_df = demand_df.rename_axis('hour', axis=0)
demand_df = demand_df.rename_axis('bus', axis=1)
```

Now the DataFrame looks like

```py
>>> demand_df.head()
bus 1           2           3           4           5
hour                    
1   0.249303    0.244917    0.348141    0.559970    0.414997
2   0.803017    0.940600    0.474955    0.976134    0.185487
3   0.776821    0.940770    0.482725    0.510914    0.186607
4   0.705604    0.871578    0.154195    0.943887    0.913865
5   0.039853    0.978370    0.320563    0.923042    0.591475
```

An easy way to obtain a dictionary `{(hour,bus):value}` is by doing:

```py
demand_d = demand_df.stack().to_dict()
```

Now, you seem to want to define 0 as a default value. There are three ways (from worst to best, imho):

- use a `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
demand_d =defaultdict(int, demand_df.stack().to_dict())
```

- make sure all the columns are filled with 0 (`.fillna(0)`)
- define a default value for the parameter

```py
model.DEMAND = pyo.Param(
    model.SET_BUSES, model.SET_HOURS, 
    initialize = demand_d,
    default = 0)
```

As a final note, `AbstractModel` might help greatly reducing the effort that goes into manual data ingestion.

Comment: what if the parameters are more than 2 dimensional?

Comment: @janicebaratheon great question. The best format is to use a [tidy format](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf), i.e. only one value per row. Say that you have a third dimension "scenario", you'd have four columns in the `DataFrame`: `["scenario", "bus", "hour", "value"]`. You can convert to dictionary as follows: `df.set_index(["scenario", "bus", "hour"]).squeeze().to_dict()` (`squeeze` transforms it in a `Series`). Notably, this works with any number of dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my aproach and solved it.

You can pass a dictionary to the Param function, so I changed the demand_init function to the following:

```
def demand_init(model, data):
    init = {}
    for t in model.SET_HOURS:
        for bus in model.SET_BUSES:
            if(bus in set(data.columns)):
                init[bus,t] = data.loc[t,bus]
            else:
                init[bus,t] = 0
    return init
```

And then, I defined the parameter like this:

```
INIT_demand  = demand_init(model, data = demand)
model.DEMAND = pyo.Param(model.SET_BUSES, model.SET_HOURS, initialize = INIT_demand)
```

Both the Hours set and the Buses set must be previously defined.

I hope this helps someone.